# JPG not showing

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox

![enter image description here][1]I've tree jpg to show. Here's the html:

```
<img id="carrossel1" class="imagemCarrossel" src="/images/home/fundo_carrossel1.jpg" />
<img id="carrossel2" class="imagemCarrossel" src="/images/home/fundo_carrossel2.jpg" />
<img id="carrossel3" class="imagemCarrossel" src="/images/home/fundo_carrossel3.jpg" />
```

The first one is rendered fine. The two other not.
The image folder have:
fundo_carrossel1.jpg
fundo_carrossel2.jpg
fundo_carrossel3.jpg

The 2nd and 3rd don't show up in Chrome of Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your CSS is modifying the elements resulting in a change of display behavior. Can you post the CSS you are using to further try to help?